# How to print to console from an invoked method in platform channel?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to invoke a java method using `MethodChannel` but any console prints on the java side don't appear to be executing.

I'm trying to load a tflite model in java.

flutter side:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel("com.example.java/print");


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getFromJava,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Future<void> getFromJava() async {
    String value;

    try{
      value = await platform.invokeMethod("PrintFromJava");
      print(value);
    } on PlatformException catch(e){
      print(e);
    }

  }
```

java side:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.example.java/print";
    protected Interpreter tflite;
    protected Interpreter.Options options;


    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

        try {
            options.setNumThreads(4);
            tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(), options);
            System.out.print("I am in the try block");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
            if (call.method.equals("PrintFromJava")){
                String myString = PrintFromJava();
                result.success(myString);
            }
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            // TODO
        });
    }

    private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws Exception {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("model.tflite");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }

    private String PrintFromJava(){
        System.out.print("this is a print in java mainactivity");
        return "This is a string returned from Java";
    }
}
```

The `PrintFromJava` method works as intended and the returned string of `This is a string returned from Java` gets printed to console when I click the button, but the `System.out.println()` strings do not.

Its making it difficult to debug my code in java and also cant be sure if my model is loading or not..

P.S. I'm learning this as I code along, so if anyone knows how to load a tflite model in java and I'm doing this wrong please correct me on that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print logs to the console with [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).